# Normalization for multivariate time-series

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, lstm, normalization

I'm wondering how to normalize data in the case of multivariate LSTM predictions?

When we do unvariate time series prediction with LSTM (for example) the pandas.DataFrame **df** (df.shape = (2000,)) can be normalized as follows :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
array = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(df).reshape(-1,1))
```

How to use *scaler* when **df** has 5 columns; 4 of them are external features and we want to predict 1 column?

Answer (score 0):

`MinMaxScaler` can also be applied to the 2D array and transforms each feature independently.

Thus, your code should be nearly the same, you just do not need 'reshape' in the last line

```
array = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(df))
```